# LastRow + Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have unusual question.
How to use lastrow in Range but instead to define end of some range, just the beginning of a range? See below.

In my code they are some "empty" cells that are not entirely empty and it causes some problems.
I have tried that code to delete them:

```
With ActiveSheet
   Range("A1:L20001").Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & .UsedRange.Address & "),CLEAN(" & .UsedRange.Address & "))")
End With
```

But in label software they are still somehow there and the only option is to delete whole "empty" range manually.

Usual application for LastRow:
.Range("A2:N" & LastRow)

**But I need something like this:**

```
.Range("A" & LastRow &":N200001")
```

Comment: What's wrong with that second bit of code?

Comment: its not clear where exactly you're facing the issue

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the range you wish to return? What are it's characteristics? What is in those cells that appear empty but are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
.Range(.Cells(LastRow ,"A"), .Cells(200001,"N")).Value = .....
```